# Bit mask operation: what does the following code mean in C?

Tags: c

I am trying to debugging a piece of code at the moment and I could not figure it out what the following piece of code really does. Could anyone help me explain or give me ideas on the functionality of the following code?

```
uint8_t get_pca9955a_slave_loaded(uint8_t _slave)
      {

        uint8_t x = (uint8_t)(_slave / 16);
        uint8_t y = (uint8_t)(_slave % 16);
        uint16_t mask = 1U << y;

       if (check_pca9955a_slave_valid(_slave)) {
           return (uint8_t)((pca9955a_slaves_loaded[x] & mask) ? 1U : 0U);
        } else {
                return 0U;
               }
       }
```

Kind Regards,
Cheung

Comment: Take some example values of `_slave`, and perform the operations on paper to see what you get.

Answer (score 0):

It unpacks a byte into its high nibble x and its low nibble y.  Taking mod 16 is the same as taking the four lowest bits, and dividing by 16 is the same as taking the remaining bits.

It then uses y to calculate a bitmask and x as an offset into some kind of table of global variables that you didn’t share, checks that bit y is set in entry x or not, and returns either 1 or 0 in an unsigned byte.

Comment: Thank you for your explaination